# Will two Antimagic Fields cancel each other out?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, antimagic-field

Let's say you have two items with an antimagic field bound to each of them. What happens when they come in range of each other?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### No, they do not cancel each other out

Assuming these antimagic fields use the same rules as the [*Antimagic field*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field) spell:

> spheres created by different antimagic field spells don't nullify each other. (PHB, pg. 213)

Items and objects that just have *antimagic field* properties in published adventures always specify that the rules for it are the same as the *antimagic field* spell. For example, there is a room in a certain dungeon that is described so:

> All magic is suppressed here, *as if by an antimagic field spell.*

Comment: Guess I should've read the description more thoroughly...